# Collapsing rows by user with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to collapse the rows based on users while placing the '1' on their corresponding columns.

Each row for each user can only have one '1' so there need not be any adding to the rows following.

My df:

```
User  +1  +2  +3  +4  +5
   A   1   0   0   0   0
   A   0   1   0   0   0
   A   0   0   0   0   1
   B   0   0   1   0   0 
   B   0   0   0   1   0
```

Expected result:

```
User  +1  +2  +3  +4  +5
   A   1   1   0   0   1
   B   0   0   1   1   0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you can use `summarise_each`:

```
df %>% group_by(User) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

Edit note: replaced `summarise_each` whicih is now deprecated with `summarise_all`

Comment: can't believe i didn't know about summarise_each. thank you so much!

Comment: `summarise_each` has been discontinued in dplyr, perhaps the answer can be changed to `summarise_all()`?

Answer (score 7):

Here's alternatve `dplyr` solution

```
df %>% group_by(User) %>% do(as.list(colSums(.)))
```

---

Or a `data.table` possible implementation

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), User]
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[, as.list(colSums(.SD)), User]
```

---

Or with base R, even simpler

```
aggregate(. ~ User, df, sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

The way that I would approach this would be to convert your data to long form first, then do the aggregation, and convert back out to wide form if necessary for display purposes.

So, using `tidyr`,

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-User, names_to="rating", values_to="count") %>%
  group_by(User, rating) %>%
  summarise(count = max(count)) %>% 
  spread(rating, count)
```

The first gather converts to long form (using `p` instead of `+`):

```
> df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='User  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
   A   1   0   0   0   0
   A   0   1   0   0   0
   A   0   0   0   0   1
   B   0   0   1   0   0 
   B   0   0   0   1   0
')
> df %>% pivot_longer(
     cols=-User, names_to="rating", values_to="count")
# A tibble: 25 × 3
   User  rating count
   <chr> <chr>  <int>
 1 A     p1         1
 2 A     p2         0
 3 A     p3         0
 4 A     p4         0
 5 A     p5         0
 6 A     p1         0
 7 A     p2         1
 8 A     p3         0
 9 A     p4         0
10 A     p5         0
# … with 15 more rows
```

And the remaining steps perform the aggregation, then transform back to wide format.